# Elementary properties of the closure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Definition:

Let $X\subseteq R$ and let $x'\in R$. We say that $x'$ is an adherent point of $X$ iff $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists x\in X$ s.t. $d(x′,x)\le \epsilon$. The closure of $X$ is denoted as $\overline X$ and is defined to be the set of all the adherent points of $X$.

> Show that: $\overline{X} \cup \overline{Y} = \overline{X\cup Y}$

**Proof:** Assume that there exist a $z$ such that $z \in \overline{X} \cup \overline{Y} $ and $z \notin \overline{X\cup Y} $

since $z \notin \overline{X\cup Y} $, then $z$ is not an adherent point to $X\cup Y$

hence, $z$ is not adherent point to $X$ and to $Y$
in other words, $z \notin \overline{X}$ and $z \notin \overline{Y}$
but this contradicts with assumption

Hence $\overline{X} \cup \overline{Y} \subseteq \overline{X\cup Y}$

is my proof correct?

Comment: You have correctly proven one inclusion, to show that two sets are equal you must prove both inclusions.

Comment: And show first the little lemma: $A \subseteq B$ then $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{B}$. Then your inclusion follows as we have $\overline{X} \subseteq \overline{X \cup Y}$ and similarly for $Y$ and so their union is also a subset. Then there is no need for a proof by contradiction. The proofby contradiction is a good idea for the other inclusion, though.

Comment: In general, you probably want to avoid a proof by contradiction to prove set equality. Assuming by way of a contradiction they are unequal, then there exists an element in one that isn't in the other. Suppose it's in set X and not set Y. Deduce a contradiction that it is in set X from the fact that it is not in set Y. You've introduced a series of double negatives you have to keep track of still having to prove $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq X$ which is necessary and sufficient in the first place.